# Creating two different Dictionaries from the original

Tags: python, dictionary

```
t = p.copy()
u = p.copy()

#split the data by events and participant frames
def remove_events(dictionary):
    for frame in dictionary['info']['frames']:
        del frame['events']
    return dictionary

def remove_participantframes(dictionary):
    for frame in dictionary['info']['frames']:
        del frame['participantFrames']
    return dictionary

t = remove_participantframes(t)
u = remove_events(u)


with open('removed_participantframes.txt', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(t, f, indent=2)
with open('removed_events.txt', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(u, f, indent=2)
```

I have a starting dictionary `p` and I want to do two different operations `remove_participantframes` and `remove_events` to create two new dictionaries `t` and `u`. Currently when uploading `t` and `u` they both have the `remove_participantframes` and `remove_events`operations applied to them.

I would like to have two different dictionaries as a result of the operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are not really making a copy of the list:

```
id(p['info']['frames']), id(t['info']['frames']), id(u['info']['frames'])
```

You can solve it by using deepcopy:

```
from copy import deepcopy
t = deepcopy(p)
u = deepcopy(p)
```

Or by generating new dicts:

```
def remove_events(dictionary):
    return {
        'info': {
            'frames': [
                {k: v for k, v in frame.items() if k != 'events'}
                for frame in dictionary['info']['frames']
            ]
        }
    }

def remove_participantframes(dictionary):
    return {
        'info': {
            'frames': [
                {k: v for k, v in frame.items() if k != 'participantFrames'}
                for frame in dictionary['info']['frames']
            ]
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `copy.copy()`, the new object is created. However, the children were not copied but referenced.
So, in your case if you want to have two different dictionaries, you should use `copy.deepcopy()`.

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/copy.html) explain the difference between them.